# How to fix Lotus Notes client for plain text email

Tags: lotus-notes, email-filter

It cannot open plain text email by default, It read cannot open default form.

I found I can do it by create a mail agent to convert them to memo manually, but if there is any way to do it automatically?

That was a lot of them coming in every day, just cannot do it one by one.

Comment: Are you using Lotus Notes with a Lotus Domino server? The server should be processing plain text email messages for you, and the Notes client should not be having a problem reading then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you talking about the default mailbox or some custom applications?
If it is your default mailbox, try to replace the design. and check wether the 
form "Memo" is set as the default form.

If this doesn't help, set your agent trigger to "before mail arrives", so your agent will be called for each and every mail. (not the optimal solution)

Comment: my mail admin discover that my design isn't update, so he update it and things are fixed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  *The reason for this comment is the fact, the answer contains answers, it isn't clear what part of the content is the actual solution to the problem.*